# Why does my mesh with a cutout have strange, jagged artifacts in other tools?

Tags: mesh, artifacts, obj

Some high school friends and I have been playing [an old FPS we used to play](http://tesseract.gg), and I've started getting into making maps. I recently dipped my toes into Blender to create some custom models for the game, and a recent project is to reconstruct a simplified version of one side of [an Acela train car](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/2R4xkY4P5JhM9oGFdOEIjdH4DRUnHLpmoh65WesE7v3bdYuj--W9f2uYpx0huy-u_J4tVRHsh6GPzkl7mPrYTSF85qLGf0xFmXDa12tIQErc6VQ).

As a starting point, I added and rotated a plane, made a loop cut to make the "bend," then used the Solidify modifier to give it some thickness.

[image: Part one of my project, creating a thick plane with a bend in it]

Then I wanted to add a hole for a window, so I created a cylinder, extruded it sideways to create an oblong shape, positioned it in the right spot, and used a Boolean modifier to take the difference. Then, I exported the mesh as a `.obj`, which is natively supported by the game. So far, in Blender and in Xcode (my most-handy OBJ-file viewer), everything looks right!

[image: My plane with a cylinder where the window would go]
[image: My plane with the Boolean modifier applied to remove the window area]
[image: My exported OBJ file previewed in Xcode]

But in the game, I've got some strange, jagged artifacts.

[image: A broken-looking version of the object running in the game]

It reminds me of the kind of things I see when a path is drawing in the wrong order (CW vs. CCW) in 2D drawing. If I apply the modifier and look at the mesh in edit mode, I can kind of visualize why things are going wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried bisecting the mesh across the window hole to create a more "sane" arrangement of faces/edges…

[image: An attempt at bisecting the plane]

… but it doesn't look much different in the game. Any thoughts on what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe rework your topology, keep only one face, use the knife tool (K to activate, C to cut perpendicularly) try to keep only quads, extrude to give thickness back.

[image]

Comment: I'm still working my way through figuring out *exactly* how to get it working the way I want, but creating a grid of quads like above made it work a lot better. Using the Boolean modifier still produces unexpected results, so I think I'll need to get better at figuring out how knife project works.